# How can i pass value from ViewController to tabbar and then tabor to ViewController to the first selected item in tabbar

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

How can i pass value from ViewController to tabbar and then tabor to ViewController to the first selected item in tabbar which is selected from start

in first ViewController

```
tabBarViewController* infoController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarViewController"];
    infoController.adView = adView;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:infoController animated:YES];
```

in tabbar view controller:

```
 UIViewController *destView = [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] topViewController];
    NSLog(@"%@", destView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIViewController *destView = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", destView);
    if ([destView isKindOfClass:[vc class]])
    {
        vc *destinationViewController = (vc *)destView;
        destinationViewController.adView = self.adView;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.